Error in buildroot: FileNotFoundError:[Errno2]No such file or directory:'.../buildroot/board/orangepi/orangepi-5/rkbin/bin/rk35/rk3588_bl31_v1.45.elf'
There is a problem: I am trying to build a buildroot for subsequent download to orange pi 5.
I've copied the repository from git. After that, I perform the following steps: make menuconfig -> make orangepi_5_defconfig -> make. The build is not completed and messages appear:
//----------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/broinstein/Projects/buildroot/output/build/uboot-custom/arch/arm/mach-rockchip/decode_bl31.py", line 53, in 
main()
File "/home/broinstein/Projects/buildroot/output/build/uboot-custom/arch/arm/mach-rockchip/decode_bl31.py", line 50, in main
generate_atf_binary(bl31_elf);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/broinstein/Projects/buildroot/output/build/uboot-custom/arch/arm/mach-rockchip/decode_bl31.py", line 38, in generate_atf_binary
for index, entry, paddr, data in unpack_elf(bl31_file_name):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/broinstein/Projects/buildroot/output/build/uboot-custom/arch/arm/mach-rockchip/decode_bl31.py", line 18, in unpack_elf
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/broinstein/Projects/buildroot/board/orangepi/orangepi-5/rkbin/bin/rk35/rk3588_bl31_v1.45.elf'
ls: cannot access 'bl31_0x*.bin': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/home/broinstein/Projects/buildroot/board/orangepi/orangepi-5/rkbin/bin/rk35/rk3588_bl32_v1.15.bin': No such file or directory
//----------------------------------------------
There is an orangepi/orangepi-5/cliche folder on my computer, but it is empty and there are no subsequent sections.
How can I solve this problem?
I've tried to execute:
sudo apt update -> sudo apt upgrade -> make clean -> make
But it was unsuccessful

There is no make orangepi_5_defconfig in the upstream/official Buildroot, so you should check with whatever special fork of Buildroot you're using (or even better: not use this fork at all, and use official/upstream Buildroot)

Thank you for your advice.
But I found what the problem was: in the repository that I copied there were links to other repositories that I did not notice and did not clone. I have cloned the repository again using the --recursive flag. After that, the build was completed successfully.
git clone --reursive ...
